# Can't PUT ModelViewSet Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am not sure why I can't do PUT requests to my ModelViewSet like shown in the documentation however PUT does not work. Any ideas? I have included my view and serializer below.

```
class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    filter_fields = ('user', 'id', 'account_type')

class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile`

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_MODEL_SERIALIZER_CLASS':
        'rest_framework.serializers.ModelSerializer',
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_FILTER_BACKENDS': ('rest_framework.filters.DjangoFilterBackend',)
}
```

Comment: You have an extra quote character at the end of UserProfile. Could be that?

Answer (score 8):

Is it possible that you are not making the request right? You need to specify the object you are trying to update in the url.

For example, the url needs to include the id of object you are trying to update:
http://localhost:8000/api/user/16/

You get the "Method \"PUT\" not allowed." when you don't specify the object in the request.

Answer (score 4):

By what you've shown here it should be working. PUT does not work in List view, only in object  Detail view. Try creating an object and look into it's detail view and check if you can see a PUT button there

Answer (score 0):

In your PUT request, you should have a parameter with the name '_method' and the value 'PUT'. That's it.